# Why is jsdom throwing a Type Error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-webkit, node-modules

I use [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) to parse remote site, but when I try to use it with node-webkit.js, it throw error:

> Uncaught TypeError: A 'super' constructor call may only appear as the
>   first statement of a function, and its arguments may not access
>   'this'. Other forms are not yet supported.

But if I use it via terminal - it works! How to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the latest and greatest jsdom

> Note that as of our 7.0.0 release, jsdom requires Node.js 4 or newer (why?). In the meantime you are still welcome to install a release in the 3.x series if you use legacy Node.js versions like 0.10 or 0.12. **There are also various releases between 3.x and 7.0.0 that work with various io.js versions**

node-webkit is based on **iojs v1.2.0** (which is pre node.js 4)

Comment: Thank you, so is it impossible to install node 4 in nwjs? I though iojs and node.js united.

Comment: nwjs is the slow cousin - even the "alpha" is only up to iojs 1.5!!

Comment: And can't I parse page(I just need <title> tag value) without jsdom? Have node or js another method to solve this problem?

Comment: did you read the answer? **There are also various releases between 3.x and 7.0.0 that work with various io.js versions**